# read of Inputstream non stop when internet connection lost

Tags: android, android-asynctask, inputstream

I'a using a asynctask to download file. It works normally until i turn off wifi connection (there are no other internet connection) of my android, download dialog still and no changes. When i check by log, i discover that function read() of inputstream is non stop. So how to check this case? here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL(this.url);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(1000);
        connection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
        fileName = "temp.zip";

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path+fileName);

        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024000];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        Log.v("test download:","download in background");
        while (((count = input.read(buffer)) != -1)) {
            Log.v("test download:","read:"+count);
            total += count;
            publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength - 1));
            output.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
```

Comment: Is there any difference if you try using smaller buffer (and more read requests)?

Comment: no, always having the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you already set a timeout by calling [`setReadTimeout()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout(int)), you should get a `SocketTimeoutException` shortly after the connection dropped.

Do your code happen to maybe capture this exception silently?

Answer (score 0):

Your file download buffer size is too much  `byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];` is enough

when i try this [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) (top answer) with asynctask ,work fine, didn't get that problem